# Likelihood that $A$ is more reliable than $B$

Tags: probability

Suppose that there are two seller $A$ and $B$ of the same product with different rating scores: A $\rightarrow$ 9 positive and 1 negative reviews and  B$\rightarrow$ 2 positive 0 negative reviews. Intuitively I would buy the product at A since it has simply more positive ratings than B. However, how can I prove this mathematically ?

I know that the likelihood to have a reliable seller is for A $P_a(R|A+)=\frac{9}{10}$ and not reliable $P_a(R|A-)=\frac{1}{10}$. But how to deal with seller B formally ? 
I would guess, $P_b(R|B+)*P(B+)=\frac{2}{2}*\frac{1}{2}$ since there is no negative review I have a 50% chance of a negative experience ?

Comment: You have not justified why $\Pr(B+) = \frac{1}{2}$.  There is no reason to believe that it is equally likely that a customer will have a good or bad experience with a vendor.

Comment: I admit the odds could be slightly better than $P_r(R|B+)=\frac{1}{2}$ as the  vendor $B$ has already 2 positive reviews. So the next review could be a good one with a probability of what $P_b(R|B+)*P(B+)=\frac{2}{2}*\frac{1}{3}$ since I have to consider 2 positive + 1 negative for all possible events. Any suggestions ?

Comment: ...sorry I mean $P_b(B+) =\frac{2}{3}$.